# No conversion with Integer.ParseInt()

Tags: java, data-conversion, parseint

I have a problem that when I use Integer.parseInt in this context it doesn't convert my and somehow it even kick me out of loop so it dont't want to display for example System.out.print(1) after loop like everything was crashed but i have no error. Please help. That's a part of code which cause it. variable "input" is an Arrayl

```
for (int i=0;i<input.size();i++) 
{
    if(point>Integer.parseInt(input.get(i).split(":")[1]))
    {    
        input.set(i,highScore + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        break;
    }               
}
```

Comment: you have a break sentence inside the if clause, when it evaluates to true, it will of course kick out of the loop without any error. Oh and also, Integer.parseInt() can throw NumberFormatException.

Comment: Yes but if i comment it all and let say take       System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(input.get(i).split(":")[1])) it won't show me anything, so i think that with that is a problem

Comment: put your Integer.parseInt in a try catch block and seek for NumberFormatException

Comment: Oh and by the way, when you say you coment it all, what does it mean exactly? you comment the loop? only the inner part of the loop?
And when you say, you use System.out.pring(Integer.parseInt(input.get(i).... etc, where do you do it? inside the loop? outside the loop?

Be more specific

Comment: It means that in loop i put only System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(input.get(i).split(":")[1])); and it didn't show me anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified that input.get(i).split(":")[1] gives you exactly a string that only contains digits?

Integer.parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException, so you should execute that code inside a try/catch block like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<input.size();i++) {
  try {
    int parsedValue = Integer.parseInt(input.get(i).split(":")[1]);
    // do whatever you want to do with parsedValue
  }
  catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.print("I caught an error!, what i was trying to parse wasn't a number");
    // or any other action you consideer that needs to be done when parseInt fails
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one explanation (if you are sure that no exception is thrown): the `input` is empty. :)

Comment: wouldn't input.get(i) throw a NPE?

Comment: No, that line is not executed if the `input` is empty. And it would not be NPE, but AIOOBE.